# Not able get output after exporting java project using eclipse

Tags: java

I am working on a java project. but I have one problem,  Not able to get output after exporting java project using eclipse. but I am able to execute the project successfully when running the project within Eclipse IDE. When I Export as runnable jar when the result(Image) not displaying. And I have dependencies in my project that are jars I am adding them from my system as G:/project/jar files. something like this.

Is there any way to debug the runnable jar.  If any please let me know, please. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Ideally if you want an executable jar you should have a MANIFEST.MF within the jar. Can you check if you have got one. Also, while running from command line you must update the classpath i.e. the path where JRE will search for additional jars (In your case it should be G:/project/jar).

Comment: Where to find MANIFEST.MF?\

Comment: I don`t have MANIFEST.MF file? can you help me to find he file?

Comment: You must have it in your generated jar. You can use any open source decompiler to check in the generated jar. A simple one can be found here http://jd.benow.ca/.

Comment: I found MANIFEST.MF file in META-INF in my jar. What to do next.

Comment: Does your MANIFEST.MF have all the classpath entries i.e. the path of your Java project ? I mean this is the classpath entry that takes precedence and hence you must have the path to additional jars set here. However eclipse has a way to copy all the dependent jars alongside your generated jar.

Comment: This is MANIFEST.MF file content as shown below

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: demo.sphinx.helloworld.Speech

Comment: While exporting using eclipse please try to use the option "Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR".

Comment: now the MANIFEST.MF file has all the classpath. but project not working as required.

Comment: same as last problem

Comment: How does your command line look like ?

Comment: I am not using any command line.

Comment: my project working is    Speech to  TEXT then TEXT to Image display as a Result.

Comment: You question was confusing as you meant "When I Export as runnable jar when the result(Image) not displaying". If you need to debug you running jar you need to start the JAVA process in JPDA remote debugging mode something like `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n` while starting your process and then you can attach your IDE i.e. source code to it. You can refer to this article for further details: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/debug-your-java-code-with-ease-using-jpda/